# Probability, expected number

Tags: arrays, variables, random, permutation, probability

In an unsorted array, an element is a local maximum if it is larger than
both of the two adjacent elements. The first and last elements of the array are considered local
maxima if they are larger than the only adjacent element. If we create an array by randomly
permuting the numbers from 1 to n, what is the expected number of local maxima? Prove
your answer correct using additivity of expectations.

Im stuck with this question, i have no clue how to solve this...

Comment: Better for Cross Validated forum... (I didnt put the negative vote, by the way...)

Comment: Please try some algorithm at your end and then come up with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an unsorted Array array with n elements. You've got two possible positions for where the local maxima could be. The local maxima could be either on the end or between the first and last element. 
Case 1:
If you're looking at the element in either the first or last index (array[0] or array[n-1]) What's the probability that the element is a local maxima? In other words what's the probability that the value of that element will be greater than the element to its right? There are 10 possible value each index could hold {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. Therefore a 50% chance that on average the element in the first index will be greater than the element in the second index. (array[0] > array[1])
Case 2:
If you're looking at any element that ISNT the first or last element of the array, (n-2 elements) then what's the probability that each one will be the local max? Similarly to the first case, we know there are 10 possible values each index could hold, therefore a 1/3 chance that on average, the element we choose will be greater than the one before it and greater than the one after it.
Putting it all together:
There are 2 cases that have a 1/2 probability of being local maxima and there are n-2 cases that have a 1/3 probability of being local maxima. (2 + n-2 = n, all possible cases). (2)(1/2) + (n-2)(1/3) = (1+n)/(3).

Comment: A pretty good answer for a pretty bad question. As a side note, please refrain from answering off-topic questions; we don't want to encourage that kind of thing here.

Comment: Im sorry if this question is off-topic because this is my first time using stackoverflow. I don't know where to put this problem to the right topic that would match the requirement of this website. Any helps would be really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Solvable of course, but won't deprive you the fun of doing it yourself. I will give you a tip. Consider this sketch. What do you think it represents? If you figure this out, you will know that a pattern is available to discover for any *n*, odd and even. Good luck. If still stuck, will tip you more.
[image]

Comment: Could you please write up your solution? I'm quite curious to see and compare

Comment: No, no-write-your-solution, but yes-more-hints :-) Hint? Sure. The zigzag in the image has 9 vertices. Each vertex is to me marked with a number from 1 to 9. What happens if you assign the lowest number to the vertex with the lowest y-coordinate? And then, what happens if you create the sequence as a result of reading the numbers assigned from the lowest y-coordinate vertex to the highest? What do you realize about what that sequence gives you?

Comment: More clearly, follow this algorithm. Assign the lowest number to the vertex with the lowest y-coordinate. Assign the next lowest number to the next lowest y-coordinate vertex and so on until all numbers are assigned. Now what do you see when you look at the upper zigzag tips? What can you tell about each tip and its immediate neighbours?